# Disallow selection of some ListView items, but still get click events?

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm using a simple `ListView` for my navigation drawer, with `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` set in the layout XML. This allows me to use a selector for the text color:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/primary_500" />
    <item android:color="@color/text_primary" />
</selector>
```

Which will color the selected item with `primary_500` and the rest with `text_primary`.

---

The above is working fine, but one of the items will launch a new activity instead of loading a fragment, so it should never be made the `ListView`'s selected item.

I've tried reverting it with this:

```
public void selectItem( int index ) { selected_item = index; }

public void revertSelectedItem() {
    int y = navigation.getScrollY();
    list.setSelection( selected_item );
    list.scrollTo( 0, y );
}
```

And elsewhere:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick( ListView list, View view, int index, long id ) {
    switch( (int)id ) {
        case R.id.exampleItem_forFragment:
            /* Swap fragments */
            selectItem( index );
            break;

        case R.id.exampleItem_forActivity:
            /* Launch activity */
            revertSelectedItem();
            break;
    }
}
```

But, even though `revertSelectedItem()` is called, the selection does not change. I'm presuming that the new selection is not assigned until after `onItemClick()` returns, so my change is getting overwritten.

---

Is there a clean way to disable or revert selection changes for only certain items, but still receive click events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I just misunderstood the purpose of some methods. Changing `revertSelectedItem()` to look like this:

```
public void revertSelectedItem() {
    list.setItemChecked( selected_item, true );
}
```

behaves exactly like I want. It looks like `ListView` uses the item's "checked" state, rather than the selection, to decide which items are marked. When in `choiceMode="singleChoice"`, calling `setItemChecked()` also unchecks all other items automatically.